# Debug Android App on Device from Console

Tags: android, vim

Up until now I've been developing Android Apps in Eclipse and debugging them on a physical device (the emulator being fairly slow). For a lot of work I'd prefer to work in vim and deploy to the handset via the terminal, any suggestions on how best to achieve this? At the moment I'm working in vim with eclipse open just to run the app on the device which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [Eclim](http://goo.gl/rZxhh).

Please read [my answer](http://goo.gl/zQ9zl) to another question about Android development in Vim+Eclim.

Answer (score 0):

so you just have to press the debug button in eclipse while plugged in you device.
 As far as I know it isn't possible to debug in vim ;)

[image: Debug Button in Eclipse]

after that choose your device and there you go.

If you mean to just simply deploy it onto the device ,you have to build an ant script. After that type

```
ant release
```

and to install it

```
adb install package_signed_from_ant
```

please also refer to [android.deveoplers](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html)

Answer (score 0):

As of rev14 of the Android SDK, you can build and install your APK an an attached device using the automatically-generated `ant` targets.  Assuming you're able to build everything using `ant` from the command line, entering the following from your project directory should build and install your app.

```
 ant clean debug install
```

Attaching a real debugger (as suggested by Rafael) is another matter entirely, though.  I don't know if there are any Android debuggers other than the ones packaged in various IDEs.  This will let you debug by watching logged messages, though.